# Send a image via curl

Tags: php, curl

Try to send a file via curl

```
$file = array('file' => "@".realpath('my.jpg').";type=image/jpeg"  ); 
$test = curlPOST($file, "http://site.ru/upload/", "http://site.ru", "c.txt" ,'', 60, 1);
echo $test;


function curlPOST($post_data, $url, $referrer='', $cookie_file='', $proxy='', $timeout=60, $header=0) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.10 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: image/jpeg'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    if($referrer) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referrer);
    if($header) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    if($proxy) {curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "user:pass");
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, 1);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    if($cookie_file) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    }
    $content=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
```

In return get a white screen, if sent without a ;type=image/jpeg I get the error message that the file cannot be loaded. At the site of loading occurs via ajax. The image is a file with the right cookies too. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: the fact that you remove the MIME type and get a no file found error indicates to me that something is wrong with your filename/filepath. Double check it is in the right location

Comment: I've tried specify the full path, the file is exactly. For example: "@C:\\AppServ\\www\\test\\1.jpg" , so in response I get the file not being loaded, if you add minetype to file the curl error - failed creating formpost data

Comment: I tried copying your code and uploading to my own webserver and it is working properly. I'm using OSX but I would take a look at different options for your filename.
It also could be an issue with the server you are uploading to?

Comment: Try again on your linux server, it did not work. Here http dump looks like the query in the live http headers - http://pastebin.com/8ajmnWrx the value of the key I first got

Comment: honestly that looks like it is working. It is sending 9831 bytes and is getting a 200 response code. What is leading you to believe that is not working?

Comment: this manually, and a curl is not loaded

Comment: You can remove this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: image/jpeg'));` and try again

Answer (score 0):

i think its the server http://site.ru/ and http://site.ru/upload/ all give blank screens